# Does the SharePoint Search evaluate Numbers?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search

We have several documents in our SharePoint environment which are named like "GG8758429_BLA_98873_lorem.pdf".
To find it, we have to enter the leading "GG", neither "*G8758429" nor "*8758429" works.

What is causing this strange behavior?

Comment: This is because SharePoint does not support wildcards in the beginning of words, just in the end (it supports prefix matching but not suffix matching)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint search does support searching on numbers, but you're trying to add a wildcard notion (*) in the beginning of your search string. This isn't supported.

> For example, the following KQL queries return content items that contain the terms "federated" and "search":
>
> federated search
>
> federat* search
>
> search fed*
>
> KQL queries don’t support suffix matching.

See [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx) for the full story